# How to Add and Use an AAR in AndroidStudio Project

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aar

I am trying to use a custom aar in my android project. I found dozens of examples in StackOverflow and the Web. Many failed at build, none worked. The clearest was at
http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/05/18/reference-a-local-aar-in-your-android-project/
That came closest to working.

Here's what I did

1. Successfully created a very simple AAR (Ref.aar) from Ref.java

   ```
   // Ref.java  
   package com.ramrod.Ref;  
   public class Ref {
       // Square an integer
       public static int
       square(int val) {
           return (val * val);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Created a test project (RefTest)
3. Created folder 'libs' under RefTest/app
4. Added Ref.aar to libs
5. File->New->New Module->Import .JAR/.AAR Package.
6. Selected Ref.jar as filename->Finish (appeared successful).
7. Modified build.gradle

   ```
   // build.gradle (Module: app)  

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 27  
       buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.ramrod.RefTest"
           minSdkVersion 11
           targetSdkVersion 15
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
           }
       }
       repositories {
           flatDir {
               dirs 'libs'
           }
       }
       dependencies {
           compile( name:'Ref', ext:'aar' )
      }
   }
   ```
8. Sync build.gradle (all)
9. Added reference to Ref.aar method (square) to onCreate in RefTest main activity.

   ```
   int sq = Ref.square( 2 );
   ```
10. Build->Clean then Build->Rebuild.
    This produced *error: cannot find symbol variable Ref*

I'm sure I'm doing something naive or just plain dumb, but I can't see it.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you import an AAR from built in helper tools using Import aar/jar option,
studio creates a module with this aar.

So at this state you can see something similar to the state mentioned below.
When display panel is Android,

[image]

Change your panel mode to Project and open your testaar , you can actually see a build.gradle file for your module and the corresponding aar.

[image]

That is why your statement

```
compile( name:'Ref', ext:'aar' )
```

was not working.

To add this aar to your project(after using import aar/jar), what you can do is to first add the module to the settings.gradle (Project settings file)

```
include ':app', ':testaar'
```

then directly add to your application level build.gradle file

```
implementation project(':testaar')
```

2)Another way is to

Right-click on your Application Module ->Select Open Module Settings -> Select the Module -> Go to Dependencies tab

P.S you can also open this window from Build->Edit Libraries and Dependencies

You will come across a window as below

[image]

Click on the small + icon, then Module option and finally add the required module(testaar)

[image]

Sync your code and voila it will start working now.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Other answer was good too but this was clearer.

Answer (score 26):

You should:

1) create `aar` library and just put it in `libs` directory ( **without** "File->New->New Module->Import .JAR/.AAR Package" )

[image: see picture]

2) add to build.gradle (Module: app)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...

}
```

After that you can use `Ref.square(int);`

Your apk will contain after build:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed.

Comment: Easiest solution.